# iOS - Voice recognition - Detect people laughing

Tags: ios, algorithm, speech-recognition, detection, voice-recognition

Is it possible (maybe using SpeechKit framework by http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/ or something like that) to detect when the user is laughing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that with common speech recognition framework which requires resources and solves different task.

You have to implement laugh detection algorithm yourself. You can collect several samples from freesound or from comedies and then train a classifier.

For feature extraction you can use http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

These papers can help you:

https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/pubs/nist04-laughs.pdf
http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~knoxm/laughter_v10.pdf